# beautifulsoup: Extract ALL of a text from a field instead of text trailing off with '...'?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

From [this](http://www.conoserver.org/index.php?page=card&table=protein&id=74) page, I would like to extract all of the text in 'Notes', i.e.:

'Inhibition of N-type Ca2+ channel current through the GABAB in rat DRG neurons with an IC50 of 1.7nM (Callaghan et al. 2008) and 24.6nM in mouse DRG of an a9 KO mouse (Callaghan et al. 2010). The specific receptor remains unclear'

I wrote this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time

for each_page in range(4,5):
    try:
        page_name = 'P' + "{:05d}".format(each_page)
        res = requests.get("http://www.conoserver.org/index.php?page=card&table=protein&id=" + str(each_page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
        final_df = pd.DataFrame()

        precursor_table = soup.find_all('table',{'class':'cardtable'})
        precursor_table_df = pd.read_html(str(precursor_table))[0].transpose()
        header =  precursor_table_df.iloc[0]
        precursor_table_df = precursor_table_df[1:]
        precursor_table_df= precursor_table_df.rename(columns = header)
        print(precursor_table_df)


    except:
        pass
```

But the output for 'Notes' trails off:

'Inhibition of N-type Ca2+ channel current thro... '

Instead of: 'Inhibition of N-type Ca2+ channel current through the GABAB in rat DRG neurons with an IC50 of 1.7nM (Callaghan et al. 2008) and 24.6nM in mouse DRG of an a9 KO mouse (Callaghan et al. 2010). The specific receptor remains unclear.'

Could someone show me a better way to get the full Notes field back as a block of text?

Comment: I don't see `...` anywhere in the link you provided.

Comment: The full text is there when I ran your code - the print statement is just shortening it. Try using this for example: print(precursor_table_df.iloc[0]['Notes'])

Comment: Thanks I couldn't figure it out because it didn't look wrong, when I changed it to your method, will keep the printing issue in mind in future.

Comment: @Slowat_Kela : The output is correct.Dataframe can't show entire text on console.If you import that to  `precursor_table_df.to_csv("csvfile1.csv")` and open csv file you can see the entire text.